# How is the YIQ conversion matrix created?

Tags: colors, rgb, yuv, color-space, rgbcolor

When I search for YUV/YCbCr conversion articles, the articles always include how the conversion matrix is generated.
I'm trying to understand how the YIQ conversion matrix is generated, but I can't find any sources for it; only the conversion matrix pre-baked.
Can anyone explain how the YIQ matrix is created and how it differs from YUV/YCbCr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is some years old, but I found the answer today:

YIQ is the as YUV, with one difference: The U and V components of the YUV color space are rotated by 33° counter-clockwise:

[image]

[Source: German Wikipedia, YIQ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ-Farbmodell#Umrechnung)

So when you combine the matrix for the RGB to YUV conversion and this one, you get the YIQ matrix.

Comment: Holy moly!! Thank you so much for digging that up!  
Funny it's on German Wikipedia but not the English one. I feel like it would be valuable to edit the English Wiki entry to include this important detail.

Comment: And you also change U and V with each other.